# Can't catch exception from ChatterFeeds

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed, try-catch

I have this code. It still generates an error despite of my catching statement: **(max length=5000)**
 I can't catch this error!
This is my method and how to i catch exception from it:

```
void FeedSitesMention(Set<Id> setMention, Id parentID){
//do something
    msBodyIn.messageSegments.add(textSegment);
    fInput.body = msBodyIn;
    ConnectApi.BinaryInput binary = null;
    ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(null, feedType, subjectId, fInput, binary);

}
```

It use in another method:

```
public void someMethod(){
    Try{
        this.FeedSitesMention(setID, ev.id); 
    }catch(Exception e){
       //Do something
    }
}
```

What's problem?

Comment: Does anything show up in your debug log as a result of this? If so, can you paste it into your question?

Comment: As I known `postFeedItem(null, feedType, subjectId, fInput, binary);` is Function of API. I put some debug before and after this function. 
I just divides it to many part (25 users). but I received the first part.
(Salesforce allows 25 users or 25 groups  post at the time). what can i do to post many users or groups to chatter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd expect the Try-catch block you have to only catch an exception that's thrown as a result of your code entering the method you're calling; not where an exception is thrown from within the method after it's been called.

In essence, if you were passing invalid parameters to `this.FeedSitesMention(param1, param2)`, then I'd expect the try-catch block to be able to catch exceptions thrown by things like a `NullPointerException` or an `InvalidParameterValueException` the latter referring to a set that's empty or isn't defined to hold Ids.

I'd expect that once you're inside the method, you'll need to have your own exception handling for `max length` which I don't see in any of the code you've posted.

Comment: Hi crmprogdev! Thank you for answer my question. I have this idea:
I just divides it to many part (25 users). but I received the first part posted to chatter. other parts can't?
(Salesforce allows 25 users or 25 groups  post at the time). what can i do to post many users or groups to chatter?

Comment: You're welcome. I see that you're adding `textSegments` which I presume are long text strings with carriage returns (lines). You can count those using string methods. I'm not familiar enough with the Chatter API to respond to the new question in your comments. You may want to post a new question referencing this one. If this post answers the initial question you've asked, please help the rest of the community by marking it as having solved your question.